# Saving multiple values with StatsD

Tags: statsd

I need to save data sets like `(timestamp, event_name, event_value1, event_value2, event_value3, ...)` with StatsD. I need this to track custom events in the web app I'm working on.
[Official StatsD readme](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/) states that StatsD expects metrics to be sent in the format:

```
<metricname>:<value>|<type>
```

Is there any way to push multiple values, or any workaround to make this possible? 
We're currently using Graphite as a backend service, but it can be changed for the sake of adding this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a naming convention to capture this information:

```
event_name-timestamp-event_value1_name:event_value1|<stat type>
event_name-timestamp-event_value2_name:event_value2|<stat type>
event_name-timestamp-event_value3_name:event_value3|<stat type>
```

etc.